# Automated Excel Sheet Import from Downloaded Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

At work we have a data storage system where we keep information about equipment we've ordered. I want to take select columns from this data and put them in another sheet that is already formatted with headings and titles. I can download a spreadsheet from the storage system and save it in Excel's file format. Ideally, I'd like to have a cell in the new sheet where I can enter the name of the sheet I'm referencing, and have all of the functions I'm using adjust to pull information from that sheet. Is there a tool or function that can accomplish this?

I couldn't get INDIRECT() to work for this, although I may have misunderstood how to use this function.

I'm new, so if this question belongs somewhere else please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: indirect won't work on closed workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that I believe would have been acceptable to the poster would be to have two things:

1. Formulas that draw upon the entered name... AND the filename of the data file (presumably the description means a file is produced, likely given the same name each time, but whose sheet name for the output data differs — as in maybe the data program names the sheets for dates or some other awkward and unfortunate varying thing). They would use `INDIRECT()` in the obvious way which the poster presumably is fully able to use, hence the lack of any example formula for any corrections to it.
2. A `HYPERLINK()` formula that opens the (presumably) standardly named FILE in which a sheet has the entered name.

The idea would be to download the file with the particular sheet name. Then open the spreadsheet in question. Click the hyperlink formula in it to open the data file that was downloaded. This lets `INDIRECT()` draw the required information and lets the spreadsheet in question function as desired. The downloaded (hyperlinked) file could be left open, or immediately closed as soon as the working spreadsheet had all the updated data. Only if the formulas using `INDIRECT()` might be changed during use would the data file be required to be left open, or re-opened after the changes. Presumably that would be rarely, or never.

The idea is the `HYPERLINK()` formula uses the known filename, or if that is what was actually meant, not a sheet name, then the same entered value (filename, not sheet name) that the `INDIRECT()` formulas use.

What should make it acceptable is that the file simply needs opened for the formulas to update using its information and can then be immediately closed.

Answer (score -1):

record a macro in excel while doing the steps it should do
here are steps how to create a macro https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b#bmrecordmacro 
while recording copy the data into the formatted sheet and if finnished stop recording.
Now this macro can be used to automatically copy the data.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's not substantial enough to really help. Can you expand your answer to include how you might do this?

Comment: here are steps how to create a macro https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b#bmrecordmacro

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable. You should edit your answer to include the pertinent details. I would suggest reading the [How do I write 'good' answers](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) FAQ.

Comment: I appreciate you're answer. I'm familiar with how to create a macro, but I don't know if you can record a macro to extract information from specific cells in one sheet, then simply run the macro and have it extract information from the same cells of another sheet. The table that you would be creating would ideally would be in a separate from the one you're extracting data from.